# Another variable trying to get outside of a function

Tags: javascript

I have some functions inside of functions and I am having trouble retrieving a variable. It will be easier to show in code I want to log the var three in the testit function but not sure how to do so.

```
test();

function test(){
    var abc;
  function one(){
    abc = 1;
    two();
  }
  var three;
  function two(){
    console.log(abc);
    three = 2;
    testit();
  }
    one();

}

function testit(){
  console.log(three);
  two();
}
```

Comment: As written, it is impossible with that scope....

Comment: might be better to make test an object with one and two added to its prototype.

Answer (score 1):

to make test an object you would do the following:

```
function test(){
    this.abc = 0;
    this.three = 0;
    this.one();
}
test.prototype.one = function(){
    this.abc = 1;
    this.two();
}
test.prototype.two = function(){
    console.log(this.abc);
    this.three = 2;
}
test.prototype.testit = function(){
    console.log(this.three);
    this.two();
}
```

and run it like so:

```
testObj = new test();
testObj.testit();
```

hope this helps.

edit: BTW: if you put a call in function 'two' back to function 'testit' you'll end up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation of what's happening:

When you wrap code in a function, you get what's called [*function scope*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). This means that the scope within the function belongs to the function and not to a scope above or outside of it (whichever way you want to look at it).

A [*closure*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures) allows an expression (typically, a function, as MDN states) to have it's own scope while *sharing* the scope of it's outer or higher scope.

So, let's look at an example:

```
// This represents the global, or window, scope.
// Analogous to window.outer_var.
var outer_var = 'outer var';

function outer_func() {
    // New scope! Local only to outer_func and those
    // expressions (functions) *enclosed* by 
    // `outer_func(){...}, e.g. inner_func(){...}.
    var inner_var = 'inner var';

    // Only outer_func() or inner-enclosed (to
    // inner_func()'s definition) functions can
    // access inner_func().
    function inner_func() {
        // Another new scope! Can access inner_var
        // and inner_func_var (below). outer_func()
        // canNOT access inner_func_var, though.
        var inner_func_var = 'inner func var';
    }
}

outer_func(); // Of course, it's in scope and accessible.
inner_func(); // This will cause ReferenceError: inner_func is not defined error.
```

Simply as it is (no wrapping context, with a closure), `var outer_var` is created with the *global* or *window* scope. It may be accessed in all of the following:

1. `console(window.outer_var);`
2. `function outer_func() {console.log(outer_var);}`
3. `function inner_func() {console.log(outer_var);}` No matter where inner_func's defined.

Here, #2/3 are analogous to:

1. `function outer_func() {console.log(window.outer_var);}`
2. `function inner_func() {console.log(window.outer_var);}`

Or *global* `this`:

1. `function outer_func() {console.log(this.outer_var);}`
2. `function inner_func() {console.log(this.outer_var);}`

Now, `inner_var` is accessible from the following:

1. `function outer_func() {console.log(inner_var);}`
2. `function inner_func() {console.log(outer_var);}` Only from within `outer_func()`.

`inner_func()` may also only be accessed within `outer_func()`, because it belongs to the `outer_func()` scope, and thus is not visible/accessible outside of `outer_func()`*.

Lastly, `inner_func_var` is only accessible by:

1. `function inner_func() {console.log(inner_func_var);}` Only within `outer_func()`.

To access your `three` variable, you have three choices:

1. Make `three` globally accessible (globals are generally discouraged as they may easily introduce difficult to resolve bugs when one is overwritten by some other code).
2. Return `three` from your `test()` function. In this case the value is accessed, not the actual variable within the function.
3. Create a property as @logic8 demonstrates, so it may be accessed as a property of an object.

---

<sup>* This isn't entirely true. `outer_func()` could export a reference to the function out of scope with `return inner_func;`. This is a more advanced concept, though, and won't be addressed here in depth. [Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6sJxq/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it in a global to do so:

```
test();
var three = false;

function test(){
[..]
}

function testit(){
  console.log(three);
  two();
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this.  Use a closure

Comment: Also, this doesn't create a global.  Globals are created when variables are declared without using a var keyword.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 - If `var` is used in the global scope, [it's accessible as demonstrated](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qv6V/). However, I would discourage using globally-scoped variables wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

when you declare a variable with `var` it becomes local to that scope. If you want to access `three` in both functions, you can either declare it without var (making it global - generally frowned upon for good reasons) or declare it outside of the two functions: `var three;`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is by using the [closure pattern in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).  This wraps your javascript class in its own function so anything you declare within that file is only local to your code.

Using jQuery, this is easily accomplished like so:

```
(function($){
  //your code goes here
})(jQuery);
```

People typically do it this way so their javascript only executes when the page is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code goes here
});
```

It's a bit more complicated without jQuery if you want to execute your code when the document is ready:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   console.log('document is ready. I can sleep now'); 
 });
```

With your code, it would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var test = function(){
        //test code here
    };

    var one = function(){
        //one code here
    };

    var two = function(){
        //two code here
    };

    var three = function(){
        //three code here
    };

    var testIt = function(){
        //test code here
    };
});
```

This way, you can safely access all of your functions from the others without polluting the global namespace.

Comment: While this is a fine answer, you're making a lot of assumptions about what OP "wants to do" (and that he's using jQuery). Without seeing any "real code" (the code posted is clearly a toy), it's a bit premature to discuss design patterns. :P

Comment: Right.  I assumed OP was new to JS, so I tried to give a bit of guidance - I tend to go overboard on my answers :) What would you change/remove?  I'm happy to do it

Comment: @MikeBell also, I included the non-jquery version (though admittedly it doesn't work in IE<8 :P ) but thought it'd be good to include the jQuery version.

Comment: You make it sound as if jQuery is required (or `onDOMReady`) to have a closure. The OP doesn't indicate anything about needing a specific event handler, and your answer should not confuse the two.

Comment: Yea I feel like everyone's completely conflating this question. It's a very simple question with an incredibly simple answer: if you want to access a variable, it has to be in scope. If you want to access a variable in two different places, the variable needs to be in scope of both of those places. Pretty standard stuff.